# Redbeanphp R::load R::Store Не обновляется значение в таблице

Tags: php, redbeanphp

есть кусок кода задача которого принять колбек от сервера, проверить подпись и положить данные в две таблицы. В первой создать запись, тут все работает отлично, а во второй изменить одну ячейку. Смысл такой получаем номер заказа, по нему ищем id записи и обновляем элемент записи. вот тут что-то не так. P.S. Если вам кажется что тут все ок, дайте знать в комментариях ибо уже были нюансы  с этим бесплатным хостингом, возможно снова дело в этом. Заранее спасибо!

```
<?php
$json=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$log=json_encode($json, true);
$key = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$secret ='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
$transactionId = $json['Payment']['TransactionId'];
$signature = $json['Payment']['Signature'];
$order_id = $json['Order']['OrderId'];
$status = $json['Payment']['StatusCode'];
$requestSign =$key.':'.$transactionId.':'.strtoupper($secret);
$sign = hash_hmac('md5',$requestSign,$secret);
if(!empty($json)){
if ($sign == $signature) {  
$transaction = R::dispense('transaction');
$transaction->transaction = $json['Payment']['TransactionId'];
$transaction->status = $json['Payment']['Status'];
$transaction->error = $json['Payment']['ErrorDescription'];
$transaction->order = $json['Order']['OrderId'];
$transaction->log = $log;
R::store($transaction);
$find_id = R::findOne('orders', 'order = ?', [$order_id] );
$id = $find_id['id'];
$orders = R::load('orders', $id);
$orders->status = $json['Payment']['Status'];
R::store($orders);  
};
};


?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спустя 2 часа оказалось все просто..... Нельзя называть столбец "order". Ибо потом при поиске по этому параметру начинает ругаться БД ибо "order" зарезервированный параметр. Сейчас все работает! Всем удачи!